# close dropdown menu after click on link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown menu which is almost complete with just 1 bug/issue that I can't figure out. My nav links to different areas on the home page. So on the home page the user can click a nav link which would instantly take them down to the desired location on the page.

**My issue comes as the user clicks on the nav link they are brought to the location but the dropdown menu will not close.**

Next to this I also want to animate my menu from top to bottom, so it looks more elegant.
I tried lots of things but I can't seem to make it work..
Hopefully you can help me out!

```css
.toggle, [id^=drop] {
     display: none;
}
 nav {
     margin:0;
     padding: 0;
     float: center;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 400;
     border: solid 0px;
}
 nav ul {
     float: center;
     position: relative;
     width: 100vw;
}
 .menu{
     background: rgb(233, 233, 233);
     background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(233, 233, 233,0.9) 40%, rgb(255, 101, 207) 99%);
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(233, 233, 233,0.9) 40%, rgb(255, 101, 207) 99%);
}
 nav ul li {
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     margin: 0px;
     display:left;
}
 nav a {
     font-family: 'OggR';
     color: black;
     font-size:14px;
     text-decoration:none;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     transition: 0.3s;
}
 .toggle + a, .menu {
     display: none;
}
 .toggle {
     position: fixed;
     display: block;
     padding:4px 20px;
     color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
     font-size:20px;
     text-decoration:none;
     width: 20px;
     height: 30px;
     z-index: 9999999999999999999;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <label for="drop" class="toggle">&#x2630;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
      <ul class="menu">
          <li>
          <li><a href="#abstract">ABSTRACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#introduction">INTRODUCTION</a></li>
          <li><a href="#chapterI">I. <br>THE MEANING OF NOSTALGIA IN CULTURAL HISTORY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#chapterII">II. <br>CONTEMPORARY NOSTALGIA</a></li>
          <li><a href="#chapterIII">III. <br>THE TWO FACES OF NOSTALGIA</a></li>
          <li><a href="#conclusion">CONCLUSION</a></li>
          <li><a href="#bibliography">BIBLIOGRAPHY</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: do you have js file? if yes please share, if not let me know i can post js code to show you how to achieve it

Comment: where is the code that opens/closes the menu? because your CSS doesn't

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, I indeed have js:

Comment: `function myFunction() { document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show"); } window.onclick = function(event) { if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) { var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content"); var i; for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) { var openDropdown = dropdowns[i]; if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) { openDropdown.classList.remove('show'); } } } }`

Comment: @sachava don't use javascript, you can do this with just 1-2 line of CSS. I have added the answer, check it out.

Comment: @sachava do you want something like this: https://stackoverflow-sachava.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

html. i added ids:

```
<nav>
      <label for="drop" class="toggle" id="toggle">&#x2630;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
          <ul class="menu" id="menu">
              <li>
              <li><a class="navLink" href="#abstract">ABSTRACT</a></li>
              <li><a class="navLink" href="#introduction">INTRODUCTION</a></li>
              <li><a class="navLink" href="#chapterI">I. <br>THE MEANING OF NOSTALGIA IN CULTURAL HISTORY</a></li>
              <li><a class="navLink" href="#chapterII">II. <br>CONTEMPORARY NOSTALGIA</a></li>
              <li><a class="navLink" href="#chapterIII">III. <br>THE TWO FACES OF NOSTALGIA</a></li>
              <li><a class="navLink" href="#conclusion">CONCLUSION</a></li>
              <li><a class="navLink" href="#bibliography">BIBLIOGRAPHY</a></li>
          </ul>
    </nav>
```

css: i gave menu postion absolute and i added top: -100% to make it "dissapear", i deleted the position of nav, i added class .menu.open to handle the open, i added transition to .menu for the animation.

```
.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
    display: none;
}

nav {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
  float: center;
  z-index: 400;
  border: solid 0px;
}

nav ul {
float: center;
    position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
    }
.menu{
  position:absolute;
  top:-100%;
  background: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(233, 233, 233,0.9) 40%, rgb(255, 101, 207) 99%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(233, 233, 233,0.9) 40%, rgb(255, 101, 207) 99%);
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}
.menu.open{
  top:30px;
}
nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    display:left;
    }

nav a {
  font-family: 'OggR';
    color: black;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

    

    .toggle {
      cursor:pointer;
    position: fixed;
        display: block;
        padding:4px 20px;
        color:black;
        font-size:20px;
        text-decoration:none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 9999999999999999999;
    }
```

and this is the js:

```
//adding the click event to the toggle
let menu = document.getElementById('menu')
let toggle = document.getElementById('toggle')
let links = document.getElementsByClassName('link')

for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
  links[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    menu.classList.remove('open')
    toggle.innerHTML = '&#x2630'
  })
}


document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  if(menu.classList.contains('open')){
    menu.classList.remove('open')
    toggle.innerHTML = '&#x2630'
  } else {
    menu.classList.add('open')
    toggle.innerHTML = 'X'
  }
})
```

Edit:
I added class to the  and i loop through them and give event on click to each link so when you click it will close the nav.

check the code pen now
https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/PoGyXwx
you can see it here

---

To be able to implement it in your page:

1. add to each `<a class="navLink">` (check the HTML above)
2. add id to manu element and to toggle element `<ul class="menu" id="menu">` and `<label for="drop" class="toggle" id="toggle">&#x2630;</label>`
3. add to your css `.menu.open {display:block}`
4. create navHandler.js file and add it to your HTML ```
   5.copy this code and past it in your navHandler.js file:

```
let menu = document.getElementById('menu')
let toggle = document.getElementById('toggle')
let links = document.getElementsByClassName('navLink')

for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
  links[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    menu.classList.remove('open')
  })
}
```

if you follow the steps correctly it should work

Comment: There is no need to add these many lines of code when you can do so with just 1-2 lines of code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But unfortunately it still does not work within my code. The menu does not close when I click on one of the links

Comment: @Elnatanvazana it works great in your example! I think the problem for me now is that it does not work with other parts in my code... I have no idea what it could be though. But sending you my complete code would be a bit too much I guess haha. here is a link to my GitHub page https://kabk.github.io/go-theses-21-sacha-van-alfen/LandingPage.html

Comment: @sachava i edited the answer check the last section of my answer

Comment: @Elnatanvazana I followed all the steps but it does still does not work. I don't know what the problem can be.

Comment: @Elnatanvazana do you maybe think I should again upload a question but then adding my whole html, css and js code?

Comment: I had mistake with ```let links = document.getElementsByClassName('link')``` it should be ```let links = document.getElementsByClassName('navLink')``` on your comment to your question you added js script and i see there "show" class. and on your question it seems like there is no show class. please create code pen or any code snippet with more code

Comment: @Elnatanvazana I made a code pen, but I now only don't know yet how to add a navHandler.js file https://codepen.io/sachavalfen/pen/QWKZoZo

Comment: Thank you, i fixed it , please copy paste the code from this code pen : https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/OJRBGMd  if it works please mark this answer as the answer to your question. thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for javascript, just add this to your css:

```
#drop:checked + .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/poExqJv

Comment: i agree but, notice in this case you dont change the toggle to X. i would prefer to use js because it opens many options. but he is right you can solve it with one line.

Comment: @Elnatanvazana, In that case, there is no need to use `input checkbox` in the HTML to trigger it. We can do it with any other element.

Comment: @Elnatanvazana @ ManasKhandelwal thank you both! but the problem remains that the menu won't close after clicking on one of the links, and it does not animate from top to bottom.

Comment: Let me give you a better way to do so.

Comment: @sachava do you want something like this: https://stackoverflow-sachava.netlify.app/